# printing static header with table data beneath of it using html and css

Tags: html, css, pdf, printing

Is there any way where by I can fix the header Div of my page and still print the Table beneath of it which have records.

What i want to do is print header section on every page with table data.I did try my best but some how whenever i fix the header Table's data gone under it so i can not see any records when i print from chrome(Ctrl + P).Is there any way i can print header on every page with data when i Ctrl+p.

So no matter how many records are there in table it will print appropriately and if you scroll down in print window still it looks classy to see.

Ref : [Having Google Chrome repeat table headers on printed pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211229/having-google-chrome-repeat-table-headers-on-printed-pages)

Ref : [How to deal with page breaks when printing a large HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763639/how-to-deal-with-page-breaks-when-printing-a-large-html-table)

[Print table header in subsequent pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924951/print-table-header-in-subsequent-pages)

```html
<div id="brds" class="t-IRR-region lto954287039941352276_0 js-apex-region" role="group" aria-labelledby="brds_heading">
  <h2 class="u-Visuallytext" id="brds_heading">Order_Item_Line</h2><input type="text" id="P79_CUST_NAME" name="P79_CUST_NAME" value="Ajay Thakor"><input type="text" data-for="P79_CUST_NAME" value="Mq8Bx7uwREXiBiK9y-COjLqUyQQ"><input type="text" id="P79_CUST_MOBILE_NO" name="P79_CUST_MOBILE_NO" value="6352417874"><input type="text" data-for="P79_CUST_MOBILE_NO" value="50B7o-_pjrjXfXH0HCKumhL99yA"><div id="brds_ir" class="a-IRR-container"><div id="brds_worksheet_region" aria-live="polite" class="a-IRR"><div id="brds_single_row_view" class="a-IRR-singleRowView"></div><div id="brds_full_view" class="a-IRR-fullView"><div id="brds_column_search_drop" class="a-IRR-colSearch"></div><div id="brds_content" class="a-IRR-content"><div id="brds_dialog_js" class="a-IRR-dialogBody" style="display:none"></div><style id="brds_worksheet_css" type="text/css">
</style>
<input type="text" id="brds_worksheet_id" value="954287388559352277">
<input type="text" id="brds_app_user" value="7984229007">
<input type="text" id="brds_report_id" value="954290687465352307">
<input type="text" id="brds_view_mode" value="REPORT">
<input type="text" id="brds_row_select" value="50">
<div id="brds_chart" class="a-IRR-chartView"></div><div id="brds_group_by" class="a-IRR-groupByView"></div><div id="brds_pivot" class="a-IRR-pivotView"></div><div id="brds_data_panel" class="a-IRR-reportView"><div class="a-IRR-tableContainer"><table summary="" class="a-IRR-table" id="954287388559352277">
<tbody><tr><th class="a-IRR-header" id="SR_NO"><span class="a-IRR-headerLabel">Sr.</span></th><th class="a-IRR-header" id="code"><span class="a-IRR-headerLabel">Code</span></th><th class="a-IRR-header" id="t_name"><span class="a-IRR-headerLabel">Particular</span></th><th class="a-IRR-header" id="t_remark"><span class="a-IRR-headerLabel">Remark</span></th><th class="a-IRR-header" id="t_qty"><span class="a-IRR-headerLabel">Qty.</span></th><th class="a-IRR-header" id="t_rate"><span class="a-IRR-headerLabel">Rate</span></th><th class="a-IRR-header" id="C168045829211209454"><span class="a-IRR-headerLabel">Amount</span></th></tr>
<tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">1</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90005</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Regular Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">          11.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">950.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">10,450.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">2</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           6.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,450.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">8,700.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">3</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90001</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Regular</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">350.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">350.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">4</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90011</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Reparing / Service</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">100.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">100.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">5</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90007</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Essilor Cryzal Glasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">650.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">650.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">6</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90003</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Titan EYE+ Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">800.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">800.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">7</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90008</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Regular Glasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">350.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">350.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">8</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90004</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Lenskart Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">650.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">650.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">9</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90005</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Regular Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,150.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,150.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">10</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90007</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Essilor Cryzal Glasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">650.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">650.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">11</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90009</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Bosch &amp; Lomb Lenses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">450.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">450.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">12</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90002</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">FastTrack Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">13</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90010</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">AquaFresh Lenses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">350.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">350.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">14</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90002</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">FastTrack Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">15</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90011</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Reparing / Service</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">100.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">100.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">16</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90002</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">FastTrack Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">17</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">18</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">19</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90005</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Regular Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,150.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,150.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">20</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">21</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90002</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">FastTrack Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">22</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90002</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">FastTrack Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">23</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90002</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">FastTrack Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">24</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90009</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Bosch &amp; Lomb Lenses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">450.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">450.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">25</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90002</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">FastTrack Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">26</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90005</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Regular Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,150.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,150.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">27</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90005</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Regular Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,150.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,150.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">28</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90004</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Lenskart Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">650.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">650.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">29</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90002</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">FastTrack Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">30</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90003</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Titan EYE+ Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">800.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">800.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">31</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90008</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Regular Glasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">350.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">350.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">32</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90003</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Titan EYE+ Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">800.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">800.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">33</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90005</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Regular Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,150.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,150.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">34</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">35</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90011</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Reparing / Service</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">100.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">100.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">36</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90007</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Essilor Cryzal Glasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">650.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">650.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">37</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90003</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Titan EYE+ Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">800.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">800.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">38</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90004</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Lenskart Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">650.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">650.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">39</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90008</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Regular Glasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">350.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">350.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">40</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">41</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90010</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">AquaFresh Lenses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">350.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">350.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">42</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">43</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">44</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90003</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Titan EYE+ Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">800.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">800.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">45</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">46</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">47</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90011</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Reparing / Service</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">100.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">100.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">48</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90003</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Titan EYE+ Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">800.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">800.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">49</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">50</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="a-IRR-paginationWrap a-IRR-paginationWrap--bottom"></div></div></div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

So if you run the snippet there is 50 records what i want is Header section should be fixed and repetitive when we control + p .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated version:

```html
<div id="brds" class="t-IRR-region lto954287039941352276_0 js-apex-region" role="group" aria-labelledby="brds_heading">
  <h2 class="u-Visuallytext" id="brds_heading">Order_Item_Line</h2><input type="text" id="P79_CUST_NAME" name="P79_CUST_NAME" value="Ajay Thakor"><input type="text" data-for="P79_CUST_NAME" value="Mq8Bx7uwREXiBiK9y-COjLqUyQQ"><input type="text" id="P79_CUST_MOBILE_NO" name="P79_CUST_MOBILE_NO" value="6352417874"><input type="text" data-for="P79_CUST_MOBILE_NO" value="50B7o-_pjrjXfXH0HCKumhL99yA"><div id="brds_ir" class="a-IRR-container"><div id="brds_worksheet_region" aria-live="polite" class="a-IRR"><div id="brds_single_row_view" class="a-IRR-singleRowView"></div><div id="brds_full_view" class="a-IRR-fullView"><div id="brds_column_search_drop" class="a-IRR-colSearch"></div><div id="brds_content" class="a-IRR-content"><div id="brds_dialog_js" class="a-IRR-dialogBody" style="display:none"></div><style id="brds_worksheet_css" type="text/css">
          </style>
          <input type="text" id="brds_worksheet_id" value="954287388559352277">
          <input type="text" id="brds_app_user" value="7984229007">
          <input type="text" id="brds_report_id" value="954290687465352307">
          <input type="text" id="brds_view_mode" value="REPORT">
          <input type="text" id="brds_row_select" value="50">
          <div id="brds_chart" class="a-IRR-chartView"></div><div id="brds_group_by" class="a-IRR-groupByView"></div><div id="brds_pivot" class="a-IRR-pivotView"></div><div id="brds_data_panel" class="a-IRR-reportView"><div class="a-IRR-tableContainer"><table summary="" class="a-IRR-table" id="954287388559352277">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="7">
                    <div class="print">
                      Hi some info here
                    </div>
                  </th>
                </tr>
                <tr><th class="a-IRR-header" id="SR_NO"><span class="a-IRR-headerLabel">Sr.</span></th><th class="a-IRR-header" id="code"><span class="a-IRR-headerLabel">Code</span></th><th class="a-IRR-header" id="t_name"><span class="a-IRR-headerLabel">Particular</span></th><th class="a-IRR-header" id="t_remark"><span class="a-IRR-headerLabel">Remark</span></th><th class="a-IRR-header" id="t_qty"><span class="a-IRR-headerLabel">Qty.</span></th><th class="a-IRR-header" id="t_rate"><span class="a-IRR-headerLabel">Rate</span></th><th class="a-IRR-header" id="C168045829211209454"><span class="a-IRR-headerLabel">Amount</span></th></tr></thead><tbody>
                <tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">1</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90005</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Regular Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">          11.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">950.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">10,450.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">2</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           6.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,450.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">8,700.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">3</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90001</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Regular</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">350.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">350.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">4</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90011</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Reparing / Service</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">100.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">100.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">5</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90007</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Essilor Cryzal Glasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">650.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">650.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">6</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90003</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Titan EYE+ Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">800.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">800.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">7</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90008</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Regular Glasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">350.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">350.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">8</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90004</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Lenskart Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">650.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">650.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">9</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90005</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Regular Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,150.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,150.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">10</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90007</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Essilor Cryzal Glasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">650.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">650.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">11</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90009</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Bosch &amp; Lomb Lenses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">450.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">450.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">12</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90002</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">FastTrack Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">13</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90010</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">AquaFresh Lenses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">350.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">350.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">14</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90002</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">FastTrack Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">15</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90011</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Reparing / Service</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">100.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">100.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">16</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90002</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">FastTrack Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">17</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">18</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">19</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90005</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Regular Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,150.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,150.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">20</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">21</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90002</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">FastTrack Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">22</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90002</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">FastTrack Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">23</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90002</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">FastTrack Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">24</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90009</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Bosch &amp; Lomb Lenses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">450.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">450.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">25</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90002</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">FastTrack Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">26</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90005</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Regular Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,150.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,150.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">27</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90005</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Regular Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,150.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,150.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">28</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90004</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Lenskart Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">650.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">650.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">29</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90002</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">FastTrack Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">30</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90003</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Titan EYE+ Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">800.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">800.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">31</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90008</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Regular Glasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">350.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">350.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">32</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90003</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Titan EYE+ Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">800.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">800.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">33</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90005</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Regular Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,150.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,150.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">34</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">35</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90011</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Reparing / Service</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">100.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">100.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">36</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90007</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Essilor Cryzal Glasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">650.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">650.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">37</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90003</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Titan EYE+ Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">800.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">800.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">38</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90004</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Lenskart Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">650.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">650.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">39</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90008</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Regular Glasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">350.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">350.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">40</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">41</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90010</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">AquaFresh Lenses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">350.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">350.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">42</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">43</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">44</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90003</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Titan EYE+ Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">800.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">800.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">45</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">46</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">47</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90011</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Reparing / Service</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">100.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">100.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">48</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90003</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">Titan EYE+ Frames</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">800.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">800.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">49</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr><tr><td class=" u-tL" headers="SR_NO">50</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="code">90006</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_name">RayBan Premium Sunglasses</td><td class=" u-tL" headers="t_remark"> </td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_qty">           1.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="t_rate">1,750.00</td><td class=" u-tR" headers="C168045829211209454">1,750.00</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="a-IRR-paginationWrap a-IRR-paginationWrap--bottom"></div></div></div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to do the same !!  not table header .... text items above that is my whole header

Comment: no no not that header above that header i have text items which is one div i wanted that to be a repetitive

Comment: oh, then you could use `position:fixed; top:0;` for the div you want to be visible in print styles and add marging for the table

Comment: you wont believe i have tried every possible thing from my side and after frustration i have decided to drop it here

Comment: So, I think maybe you could just add more one tr in thead and put there div that you want to reuse(with styles you theme it how you want for print or webpage)? I have updated original snippet I posted in answer so you can see what I meant

Comment: indeed that works fine but when you have more data then its getting weird.. More data in header section where you have written " Hi some info here" ... Actually i am using RAD tool so can not add <thead> ..Above snippet is actual snippet i cannot add more stuff like <thead> <tr> to it

Comment: i changed the logic in my actual env. Okay so can we do the same for footer...Like can we calculate the last row total of every page and show it on every page .. then can we add whats exact total of every page in last rendered page is it possible !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery offset functionality which allows you change the styles of certain elements after some amount of scrolling.

Comment: do you have any examples for same ??